# Certain website is not accessible in my server

Tags: linux, firewall

I cannot access a certain website in my Linux Server.

```
# curl https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?WSDL
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

It's accessible from anywhere else but my server. I disabled ConfigServer Firewall but the problem still persist. I have no idea how I can investigate the issue and realize why this page is not accessible in my server?

I would appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 2):

- Is this URL password protected, if so you'll need to pass that info.
- Does the server have a valid SSL certificate, if not you'll need to use the -k option.
- Use the -v option to get verbose output
- Try using wget with the same URL and see if that works.
- Can you ping that server?
- Can you traceroute that server?

It's possible that server has blocked you on their side.  Only thing you can do in that case is contact the administrator for that system.  I can't access it from my system, so it's not *just* your system.  May be restricted to certain networks/hosts.

[edit]

- Name or service not known == DNS problem.
- Can you ping the IP address?
- Try disabling your firewall temporarily to see if it is causing a problem.

Comment: 1) URL is not password protected
2) Yes, server has valid SSL certificate.
3) "Trying 79.170.146.134... Connection timed out"
4) "wget" did not work too.
5) I cannot ping the server
6) Traceroute: "https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir: Name or service not known"

Comment: Name service not known = DNS/resolver problem.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The error

> curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

means that the DNS is working fine, but the TCP connection failed. This is a networking issue at TCP level. Check the firewall and may be your MTU. If you have a bad firewall that filters all ICMP, then you might have problem if there is a lower MTU on the path that is smaller that the one from the local machine.

To disable certificate checking use:

```
curl -k https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?WSDL
```

Comment: For me it is working with `curl http://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?WSDL`. Try with http instead https.